# How would I send push notifications from user to admin?

Tags: javascript, php, push-notification

I'm using php, javascript & mysql. I want the server to send push notifications to the admin when an order is placed. What would be the best way to implement them. I'm using push.js to create the push notifications. My question is I how do I send them from user to the admin or vice versa.

Comment: We don't really know how to help you. Please read [Are “how would I get started?” questions too broad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308836/5947043)

Comment: Still too broad. We have no real context about your scenario, no code, and no specific _problem_ (rather than a generic requirement) to solve. See [ask].